# jQuery send ajax requests per line of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jQuery send ajax requests per line of textxtarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K7Dz.png)

i wnat to send ajax requests per line of textarea

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
                //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
                e.preventDefault();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'ajax-send.php',
                    data: {from_name: $('#from_name').val(), from_email: $('#from_email').val(),subject: $('#subject').val(),content: $('#content').val(),emails: $('#emails').val()},
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#response").html(data);
                       // alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

This code of request

Comment: You're nearly there. You need to first split the text area's text into an array of lines something like  var emails = $('#email').val().split("/n");  and then you can use a for loop to send the ajax requests

Comment: can you write example for loop and ajax request plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Split your input to create an array of each line, and then loop through the array to post each one separately. Something like this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
       //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
       e.preventDefault();
       var emails = $('#email').val().split("\n");
       for(var i=0; i<emails.length; i++)
       {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'ajax-send.php',
         data: { email:emails[i] }
    
    etc....
```

What you actually post to your ajax call will depend on what the request is expecting, but that's how you would get the relevant line from your array...